# Shinyapp Leaflet map doesn't display markers correctly in Chrome

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-leaflet

I made an RShiny app with a leaflet map that has markers. The marker icons work just fine in Safari and Firefox, but in Chrome they do not render and instead a different icon is displayed.

The app is the Interactive GSSP App. It is being hosted on shinyapps.io at: https://lotkey.shinyapps.io/interactive_gssp_app/
Here is the source code: https://github.com/lotkey/DTKB-Apps

The part where the icon is made is in appServer.R at line 43.

```r
# Make "custom" icon with golden spike image
gsspIcon <- makeIcon(
  iconUrl = "http://www2.cs.uidaho.edu/~max/image/gssp.png",
  iconWidth = 20, iconHeight = 32,
  iconAnchorX = 10, iconAnchorY = 32  
)
```

The image link is still working for me, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

[image: Markers not displaying properly in Chrome]

Comment: If you upload the image to another hosting service do you encounter the same issue? What about with a different image file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure what the issue exactly is, but instead of using an image URL I downloaded the image and included it in the app.

```r
# Make "custom" icon with golden spike image
gsspIcon <- makeIcon(
  iconUrl = "./gssp.png", # Path to local image
  iconWidth = 20, iconHeight = 32,
  iconAnchorX = 10, iconAnchorY = 32  
)
```